# How to determine when a tab's content has finished rendering using jQuery UI tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using `jQuery UI`'s tab view.  I have included my HTML below, it's a slimmed down version of what I have.

```
<div id="UserDetailsTabs">

     <ul>
          <li><a href="#tabs-1">User Details</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tabs-2">Impersonation Details</a></li>
     </ul>

     <div id="tabs-1">
          <p>Tab 1 content</p>
     </div>

     <div id="tabs-2">
          <p>Tab 2 content</p>
     </div>

</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code to create the tab:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#UserDetailsTabs").tabs();
});
```

Is there a way of determining when a tab's content has finished rendering after clicking on a tab?  What I mean is if I click on tabs-2, is there a function that can be called after the contents of the selected tab has been finished rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#UserDetailsTabs").tabs({load: function(event, ui) { 
    alert('tabs loaded')    
});
//This will trigger when user clicks a tab after the page load
$( "#UserDetailsTabs" ).tabs({
   show: function(event, ui) { alert('clicked on the tabs'); }
});
```

Comment: I tried both of your ways, the first one did not trigger at all.  The 2nd approach works just fine.  Could you please review your first approach to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   create: function(event, ui) { ... }
});

$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabscreate", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

But See the [Doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#events) to find the appropriate event.

Answer (score 0):

coolguy's answer, above, is correct.  It took me a while to find this and sort out so I thought I'd post a more complete example.  This is, in large part, from the Tabs documentation.  The only thing added is the "load:" section.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        active: <?php echo $tab ?>,
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
            ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            });
        },
        load: function( event, ui ) {
            //tab is loaded...now execute this code...
            $(".ResultsTable").tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'] }); 
        }       
    });
});
```